# How to download & transfer from Kindle or Amazon.com to PC

Tags: kindle, amazon, android, download, kindle-pc-reader

How can I download & transfer an eBook from Kindle or www.amazon.com to PC? I have the Kindle for PC and Kindle for Android apps. I can't find an option to do it in the apps.

For the web browser on www.amazon.com, under `Account > (Manage) Your Content and Devices`, clicking the `Download & transfer via USB` action for the eBook brings up the below prompt. The options in the drop down menu are the aforementioned apps, neither of which are selectable. Must I possess Kindle or Fire hardware to enable the download option?

[image: You have selected content that is not compatible with any of your registered devices. Please remove incompatible content from selection for eligible devices to appear. Transfer Tip: After downloading, use your USB cable to connect your computer and Kindle. Your Kindle will appear as a drive on your computer. Copy your downloaded file from your computer to your Kindle's documents folder.]

Answer (score 2):

The documented way is to use the Kindle PC app and download the book inside that. The file will end up on your PC and only readable in the Kindle. The current versions download the book as a .kfx file that allows Kindle apps to do more with the data. Older versions downloaded the file as a .azw file.

The USB option does need Kindle hardware. The hardware will show in the web drop down box and the file is downloaded as a .azw file to the PC.

Non DRM files can be loaded inmto apps like calibre and converted to other ebook formats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the PROPER answer but I can think of a workaround.  Use a memory stick. As it's in the USB socket, the system SHOULD say 'Ah. There's something in the socket for me to put the file onto' and just do it, then you can move it back off the stick onto the computer.  If you've got a smart phone, you should be able to use that.  Connect up the smart phone, which'll likely show up as disc drive, put it on smart phone, move it from smart phone to PC.

It's not a very good answer.  If anyone knows how to do it directly I, too, would love to read how! Right now it's the only way I know to do it, too!

Yours respectfully

Chris.

Comment: The "Download and transfer via USB" option has nothing to do with USB drives. It downloads to any drive or directory on your computer.  The page only says "USB" because you can use a USB cable to copy files from your computer to a Kindle device.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, that's part of the Amazon security, they don't want you making copies. And it's illegal to make unauthorized copies of a book with copyrights.

If you want to search around on the Kindle itself, connect your Kindle to a PC and it should appear as a drive. Look for a bunch of MOBI or AZW files. Those are your books. Except each book does not have the real title in the filename. Each filename is a bunch of garbled letters and numbers.