# Downloading Kindle books via USB

Tags: kindle

I recently rejoined Kindle Unlimited but -I'm having problems downloading to my kindle. It was easy the last time I did it but now there seems to be a big problem.  I'm using the same kindle device and the same computer, but it tells me there is 'no device eligible to download content to? has Kindle changed the system in the last 12 months?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/7622

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Send to Kindle application?
https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle